# Getting Power Options settings on a remote PC (C#)

Tags: c#, sleep, remote-access

I'm trying to obtain the following information regarding Power Options on a remote PC via C#:

- Time to sleep
- Time to turn off display
- Time to turn off hard disk on battery
- Time to turn off hard disk when plugged in
- Sleep after on battery
- Sleep after when plugged in
- Hibernate after on battery
- Hibernate after when plugged in

I'm not looking to change those settings: just reading them.
The registries in CURRENTUSER\Control Panel\PowerCfg were less than helpful, as none seem to point to the settings above.
I also tried using PowerEnumerate(), but couldn't find a way to make that function work on a remote computer.

How would I go about obtaining the value of these settings from a remote computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheme in the registry is (unnecessarily) complicated, however:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings
```

contains GUID values for the different settings, and the default values for AC and DC for the stock plans.

The key

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes
```

contains any modifications made to the Power Schemes settings under the GUIDs for each setting group and setting.

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes\ActivePowerScheme
```

contains the GUID of the currently active Power Scheme.

I would certainly not change the settings via the registry, but I believe you could read them.

For example, if your active Power Scheme is High Performance, then ActivePowerScheme contains `8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c`. If you look in `PowerSchemes\8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c` and see

```
0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442
    6738e2c4-e8a5-4a42-b16a-e040e769756e
        ACSettingIndex  REG_DWORD  0x00000e10 (3600)
```

then you know the time to turn off the hard disks on AC power is 3600 seconds or 60 minutes.

Comment: It's a mess to look at, but I can definitely work with that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to make use of Power Management Api, here is the example class [PowerManager.cs](https://github.com/andy722/power-plan-switcher/blob/master/PlanSwitcher/PowerManager.cs)
and also look into Power Scheme Management [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372711(v=VS.85).aspx)

Edit:
Something that you are seeking to capture the details from the remote PC, you can install your program in window service through which you can read the updates.